# Create inverse strings

Tags: r, string

I have a liste of strings (`selected_strings`), which are words, separated
by a comma. All of these words are from a possible dictionary (`full_string`).

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~selected_strings, ~full_string,     
  "",                         "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear",  
  "Apple",                    "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear",  
  "Apple, Cranberry",         "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear",  
  "Cranberry, Apple, Banana", "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", 
  "Banana",                   "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear",
  "Cranberry",                "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear"
)
```

I want to create the inverse string to `selected_strings` relative to the
dictionary in `full_string`.

For the `selected_string` "Apple", the inverse string relative to the dictionary
would be "Cranberry, Banana, Pear", because these are all the words that do not
show up in the original `selected_string`.

(An alphabetic sorting of these strings would be a nice-to-have, but is not necessary.)

For the full example above, this should be the outcome:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~selected_strings, ~full_string, ~inverse_string,
  "",                         "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", 
  "Apple",                    "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", "Cranberry, Banana, Pear", 
  "Apple, Cranberry",         "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", "Banana, Pear", 
  "Cranberry, Apple, Banana", "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", "Pear", 
  "Banana",                   "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", "Apple, Cranberry, Pear", 
  "Cranberry",                "Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear", "Apple, Banana, Pear", 
)
```

Comment: Something like this? `apply(df, 1, function(i) gsub(i[1], "", i[2]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have given a `tribble` assuming that you'd like a solution in `tidyverse`

```
df %>% mutate(inverse_str = map2_chr(str_split(selected_strings, ', '), str_split(full_string, ', '), ~toString(setdiff(.y, .x))))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  selected_strings           full_string                    inverse_str                   
  <chr>                      <chr>                          <chr>                         
1 ""                         Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
2 "Apple"                    Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear Cranberry, Banana, Pear       
3 "Apple, Cranberry"         Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear Banana, Pear                  
4 "Cranberry, Apple, Banana" Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear Pear                          
5 "Banana"                   Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear Apple, Cranberry, Pear        
6 "Cranberry"                Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear Apple, Banana, Pear
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think *"complementary"* is more precise than *"inverse"* for your question description.

---

You can try the code below using `mapply` + `setdiff` + `strsplit`

```
transform(
  df,
  inverse_string = mapply(
    function(x, y) toString(setdiff(y, x)),
    strsplit(selected_strings, ", "),
    strsplit(full_string, ", ")
  )
)
```

which gives you

```
          selected_strings                    full_string
1                          Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
2                    Apple Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
3         Apple, Cranberry Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
4 Cranberry, Apple, Banana Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
5                   Banana Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
6                Cranberry Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
                  inverse_string
1 Apple, Cranberry, Banana, Pear
2        Cranberry, Banana, Pear
3                   Banana, Pear
4                           Pear
5         Apple, Cranberry, Pear
6            Apple, Banana, Pear
```